# Python: try...except with wildcard for exception names?

Tags: python, exception

I want to except only exceptions thrown by mutagen.  However, there's a LOT of possible exceptions there.  Is there some way I can wildcard (via regexp/etc) the exceptions handled by except?  The alternative is just fugly...

```
mutagen.apev2.APEBadItemError
mutagen.apev2.APENoHeaderError
mutagen.apev2.KeyError
mutagen.apev2.ValueError
mutagen.easyid3.EasyID3KeyError
mutagen.easyid3.KeyError
mutagen.easyid3.ValueError
mutagen.flac.FLACNoHeaderError
mutagen.flac.FLACVorbisError
mutagen.flac.TypeError
mutagen.id3.EnvironmentError
mutagen.id3.EOFError
mutagen.id3.ID3BadCompressedData
mutagen.id3.ID3BadUnsynchData
```

and so on :P

Comment: One way is to find out out if they have a common base class (they seem to come from one library, so that is possible). Then you can catch the base class and `if exc is inherited_exc: #...` over the derived classes.

Comment: Wait, i was thinking in c# (early moning here). That should be `if isinstance(exc, inherited_exc_type)`, e.g. `isinstance(ex, mutagen.flac.TypeError)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a less fugly way of going it, although it's still a slight pain, each of those modules implements an "error" that all of the relevant errors extend from.

```
# Please note, the exception class truly is lower cased as indicated
mutagen.id3.error
mutagen.flac.error
mutagen.apev2.error

# mutagen.easyid3 errors extend the mutagen.id3.error class
```

Comment: Thanks; that at least shrinks it down by a large percentage.  :D

Comment: Its really weird that the design chooses to subclass a different `error` class in different modules. Wonder why they didn't just subclass a single Exception base class.

Comment: They absolutely did subclass Exception, they just named it error :)

Comment: This is their implementation, class error(Exception): pass Please accept my answer if it has solved your problem :)

Comment: `Exception` class doesn't help in terms of trying to isolate a custom base class that separates it from the python exceptions. And they define class error in multiple classes instead of just importing an error module and reusing it.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty ugly too, but something like it might be a viable option in a case where you need to intercept a large, very heterogenous set of exceptions. At least it sequesters the long list of exceptions elsewhere.

```
>>> errors = {NameError:'a', ValueError:'b'}
>>> try:
...     cornucopia
... except Exception as e:
...     e_type = type(e)
...     if e_type in errors:
...         print errors[e_type]
...     else:
...         raise
... 
a
```

Obviously this is to be avoided if possible; [Bryan Moyles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10477105/577088)'s solution is probably preferable in your particular case. Still, thought I'd mention it.